# Validar la información de un Formulario al momento que es sometido a modificación

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mvc, web, angularjs-scope

estoy haciendo una modificación de registros con angular y quiero validar que si su informacion cambió que actualice, en caso contrario  que le envie al usuario un alert "***Necesita cambiar al menos un registro del fomulario***", esto me lo he planteado de la siguiente manera, al momento de cargar los datos los guardo en una variable (esa es la que voy a utilizar para compararla con los nuevos datos)

//Aqui obtengo los datos que voy a modificar y los asigno a una variable llamada informacion

```
function getSuccess(response) {  
               //le asigno los datos al $scope
               $scope.infoUsuario=response.data;
               informacion = response.data; 
            }
```

//Al momento de presionar Guardar tengo el llamado de esta funcion donde le paso como parametro lo que tenga en el scope

```
 if (verificarEdicion($scope.infoUsuario))
```

pero tengo un problema con el $scope de angular, al momento de verificar cada uno de los nuevos datos con los anteriores que guarde  en la variable **informacion**  me sale lo mismo que tengo en el $scope... Pero yo en ningun momento le he pasado a la variable **informacion** los datos del **$scope**

```
function verificarEdicion(datos) {
            if (informacion.Nombre1 == datos.Nombre1 &&
               informacion.Nombre2 == datos.Nombre2 &&
               informacion.Apellido1 == datos.Apellido1 &&
               informacion.Apellido2 == datos.Apellido2 &&
               informacion.Direccion == datos.Direccion &&
               informacion.Genero == datos.Genero &&
               informacion.FechaNacimiento == datos.FechaNacimiento &&
               informacion.DepartamentosId == datos.DepartamentosId &&
               informacion.Comentarios == datos.Comentarios ) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que crear una nueva instancia para la variable `informacion` y así angular solo actualizara la referencia del objeto `$scope.infoUsuario`. `informacion = $scope.infoUsuario` comparte la referencia del objeto `$scope.infoUsuario` con `informacion`, por lo que angular al actualizar el objeto `$scope.infoUsuario` tambien actualiza `informacion`.

Mira este ejemplo:

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  
  $scope.info = {
    nombre: ""
  };
  
  var estado = {};
  $scope.guardarEstado = function(){
    estado = $scope.info; // guardamos el estado actual
  }
  
  $scope.diff = function() {
    console.log(estado);
    console.log($scope.info);
    if(estado.nombre == $scope.info.nombre) {
        alert("iguales")
    } else{
      alert("no iguales");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="app"  ng-controller="ctrl">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

  
  <input type="text" ng-model="info.nombre" />
  {{info.nombre}}
  <br>
  
  <button ng-click="guardarEstado()">Guardar estado</button>
  <button ng-click="diff()">Comprobar diferencias</button>
</div>
```

Nota como sin importar cuantas veces guardes el estado, siempre ambos objetos son actualizados ya que comparten referencias.

Para evitar esto, has una copia profunda del objeto con [`angular.copy()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy):

```js
angular.module("app",[]).controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  
  $scope.info = {
    nombre: ""
  };
  
  var estado = {};
  $scope.guardarEstado = function(){
    estado = angular.copy($scope.info); // guardamos el estado actual copiando el objeto 
  }
  
  $scope.diff = function()
  {
    console.log(estado);
    console.log($scope.info);
    if(estado.nombre == $scope.info.nombre) {
        alert("iguales")
    } else{
      alert("no iguales");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div ng-app="app"  ng-controller="ctrl">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>

  
  <input type="text" ng-model="info.nombre" />
  {{info.nombre}}
  <br>
  
  <button ng-click="guardarEstado()">Guardar estado</button>
  <button ng-click="diff()">Comprobar diferencias</button>
</div>
```

En tu caso entonces solo tienes que asignarle el resultado de `angular.copy` a `informacion`

```
 $scope.infoUsuario=response.data;
 informacion = angular.copy(response.data);
```

---

**TL;DR:**

Reemplaza:

```
informacion = response.data
```

por

```
informacion = angular.copy(response.data);
```

Comment: Gracias Einer!!! Eso era lo que necesitaba... Muchas Gracias

Comment: `informacion = angular.copy(response.data);`

Esa linea era lo que necesitaba, pero la explicacion que me diste esta super,

Comment: Fue un placer haberte ayudado. Si te sirvio, recuerda marcar la respuesta.

Comment: Listo Colega, Dios te siga dando sabiduria